# Django installing packages via symlinking

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to "install" third party django packages by sym linking them into your site directory?

For example, I'd like to use the django-registration package. However, I don't want to install django-registration into my site-packages directory. I'd rather just link django-registration/registration into my project directory as /myproject/registration.  However, this doesn't seem to work. I get the following:

Error: No module named registration

Comment: Before I started using VirtualEnv, I kept all of my Python modules in a folder called "source" and symlinked them into my Python installation's site-packages directory or into my project folder, so yes, you can do that. It sounds like there's an issue with your Python Path. Make sure your project's parent folder is on the Python Path.

Comment: You might want to consider using virtualenv/pip though. Pip can use a requirements file that will download and install all the packages listed in the file, which makes it very simple to go from a development environment to production.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, it's better to include the packages as an svn external / git module / etc. That way they're always available, even to others that checkout your project.

Short of that, virtualenv is the better solution. You still "install" the packages, but they are added to the virtual environment (hence the name). You get all the benefits of packages installed right into site-packages, without actually adding anything to site-packages.